# Is this double casting valid/correct code?

Tags: c

```
int compare_acd(const void *a, const void * b) 
{
     return ( (int)(*((ADC_VALUE_TYPE*)a)) - (int)(*((ADC_VALUE_TYPE*)b)) );
}
```

in my case `ADC_VALUE_TYPE` is `uint16_t`, but that is not rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for the outer pair of parenthesis, `return` is not a function.

Other than that, I can't see a problem ... You're casting the pointers before dereferencing, to read the proper number of bits, then "upcasting" to `int`.

UPDATE: Based on your comment, it seems you want a negative return if e.g. the value pointed at by `a` is smaller than the one pointed at by `b`, so you need to convert to a signed type. I guess that's fine, not 100% sure if it's required or not but at least it's pretty clear what's going on.

Of course it could be broken down into multiple statements for even more clarity:

```
int compare_acd(const void *a, const void * b) 
{
     const ADC_VALUE_TYPE va = *(ADC_VALUE_TYPE) a;
     const ADC_VALUE_TYPE vb = *(ADC_VALUE_TYPE) b;

     /* Cast to int to get signed response if a < b. */
     return (int) va - (int) vb;
}
```

That's probably how I'd write it.

Comment: I think that if I remove (int) it will not return negative value, since subtracting uint - uint is always non-negative, or am I wrong?

Comment: Where are the implicit brackets in this. Maybe `(int) va - (int) vb` is actually like `(int) (va - (int) vb)` ? I'm probably wrong, but I'm being paranoid. I think I'd write `((int) va) - ((int) vb)`

Comment: (Never mind my last comment). It is safe. The casting will happen before the subtraction. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence